# How to do path aliases for views like news/%?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

Let's suppose we have a view like news/%.
Where news is my content type, and % is tid of term id from vocabulary "categories".

Obviously that urls like news/3, news/5 etc. works great. But how to do the path aliases for this kind of urls, generated from this view?

I want like this:

- news/% -> company-news/[term:name]
- Example: news/3 -> company-news/accidents

(where [term:name] transliterated term name from original title, because my site not on english language)

P.s. the just using pathauto for taxonomy terms, and the view "taxonomy/term/%" does not suit, because one term is used by multiple content types, and therefore in multiple views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is quite a tricky one.

Two possible solutions:

1)
Use page manager, create a context for each content type, and then use this module to generate the aliases): https://www.drupal.org/project/page_manager_pathauto (note: no Drupal 8 version)

2) Add/remove/modify the aliases yourself with an update hook.  So when a node is updated, you create/update/delete the corresponding path aliases.

Comment: I'm used advice # 2

Comment: I'm used advice # 2.
I create a custom module for extra path alias creation, where I use hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert to generate new alias for term, when it was saved. With 
    \Drupal::service('path.alias_storage')->save($origin_path, $new_alias, $entity_language_id);